# If traumatic experiences that trigger PTSD can be blocked by a memory blocker

Tags: memory, ptsd

Basically, we're making a short film on mental disorders (we changed our topic since the last question I asked) and one major detail in our film is that the main character has PTSD and Schizophrenia and the main character also has had the memories of her traumatic experience suppressed by beta blockers (or any other memory-blocking drug). I'd like to know if it's possible to block and almost forget a traumatic experience with the assistance of a drug (also note that this drug was taken several years after the incident).

Comment: There is something called repressed memories. I am not sure how long after the fact a memory can be repressed or if they can be influenced by medications.

Comment: With propanolol you could erase the emotion attached to the experience. You won't forget the event though. Here an example treating Arachnophobia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDXWBHCusqs

Comment: There are cases where people don't remember the trauma either. I don't understand why this is a duplicate of a "prevention" question, and I would like to see this discussed too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16781